# SilverStripe Blog page not adding

Tags: composer-php, blogs, silverstripe

I am trying to add a blog to a SilverStripe site using the [Blog Module](http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/blog).

The package seemed to install fine (via `composer require silverstripe/blog`) and `dev/build` returned no errors. The ‘Blog’ page type is also available from the ‘Add page’ menu.

After adding a ‘Blog’ page, the site doesn’t redirect to http://localhost:8888/example/admin/pages/edit/show and simply remains on the http://localhost:8888/example/admin/pages/add/ page.
From what I can tell, the only result from this action is an ‘ARCHIVED’ page being added to the sitetree.

Have `?flush=all` etc as per other suggestions to no avail and other page types are still being added fine.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Currently using:

```
"silverstripe/cms": "3.6.1",
"silverstripe/framework": "3.6.1",
"phpunit/PHPUnit": "~3.7@stable"
"silverstripe/blog": "2.4.6"
```

---

[Edit 13/09/2017]

While simply adding a 'Blog' page produces no observable errors, adding a generic 'Page' and changing the page type to 'Blog' produces the following error in the `php_error.log`:

`PHP Warning:  require_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/blog/_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/framework/core/manifest/ConfigManifest.php on line 141`

`PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/blog/_config.php' (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/framework:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/framework/parsers:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/framework/thirdparty:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.30/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example/framework/core/manifest/ConfigManifest.php on line 141`

---

[Edit 13/09/2017]

Trialled the module on a clean install of SilverStripe as well as another project (both using 3.6.1 CMS and 2.4.6 Blog module); both work so far without issue. Perhaps it was an issue with this particular project. Would still be great to get clarification on what the root of this issue might have been.

Comment: This kind of question would be better suited for the SilverStripe Community Slack channel or the SilverStripe Forums since it's not showing problems with code

Comment: @RobbieAverill thanks for your response; good to know. I have posted this on both the SilverStripe Blog Module forum, as well as the SilverStripe Slack channel. Both without response so far

Comment: An error with the manifest seems to be a caching issue? Did you flush? do you have a `silverstripe-cache` directory in your webroot? delete it's content (it's just a cache). If not you might have a  cachefolder somewhere in your /tmp/, you can also delete it without problems.